# unexpected indent

Tags: python

```
a = [ 1, 2, 4, 789, 81545, 95556, 1111, 223, 330, 999, 210, 1241, 88, 560, 51]
max1 = 0
n = len(a)
for i in range (n):
    if a[i] // 1000 == 0 and a[i] % 9 != 0 and a[i]> max1:
        max1 = a[i]
print(max1)
    else:
print ("Не найдено")
```

Comment: Примите ответ если он вам помог (галочка у ответа)

Comment: @finally После 2к репутации нет ограничений на 6 символов, вам осталось ещё 800 баллов рейтинга где-то до этого рубежа. PS Систему модерации модераторы менять не могут.

Answer (score 2):

В питоне отступы имеют ключевое значение:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 4, 789, 81545, 95556, 1111, 223, 330, 999, 210, 1241, 88, 560, 51]
max1 = 0
n = len(a)
for i in range (n):
    if a[i] // 1000 == 0 and a[i] % 9 != 0 and a[i]> max1:
        max1 = a[i]
        print(max1)
    else:
        print ("Не найдено")
```